# What is the use of flex value in HBox and VBox layout in ExtJS?

Tags: extjs

From the ExtJS documentation:

```
flex : Number
This configuration option is to be applied to child items of the container managed by this       
layout. Each child item with a flex property will be flexed horizontally according to each 
item's relative flex value compared to the sum of all items with a flex 
value specified. Any child items that have either a flex = 0 or flex = undefined will not 
be 'flexed' (the initial size will not be changed).
```

But the documentation does not give a lucid application on how it affects the layout and how to use it. Also, I could not find any good tutorials/examples on how to use it on Google.

Appreciate if someone can throw more light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good usage and demo of flex at the following sites:

1. [Sencha Examples (at vbox node)](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.2a/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)
2. [Java2s](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Ext-JS/FlexAllevenhboxlayout.htm)

Answer (score 0):

It's proportional ratio for length vbox (height)  & hbox (width)